# Javascript (Userscript) Smartphone Notification via PushOver

Tags: javascript, android, push-notification, push, pushover

Im trying to send a message to my smartphone using the PushOver AVI in a Userscript.

The code looks like this:

```
function sendMsg() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json",
        datatype: "application",
        token: "xxXxXxXXXxXx",
        user: "xXxXXYXxyxX",
        device: "samsungs4",
        message: "This is a test message",
        sound: "echo",
        success: function(){ console.log("Message sent"); },
        error: function(){ console.log("Couldn't send message"); }
    });
}
```

However, when I execute this script from a random website (added as @match in the user script) I get error 400 "bad request".

According to their API my request looks just fine and I can't think of anything why it wouldn't work.

Maybe someone with more experience could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post everything as data: solves the problem.